# Javascript: settimeout problem

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

When I start my script I have this:

```
var my_great_masterpiece = new function ()
{
        var self = this;
```

Then later in my script I have this:

```
        response_xml: function ()
        {
            if (self.http_request.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (self.http_request.status == 404 && countXmlUrl <= 3)
                {
                    countXmlUrl++;
                    self.realXmlUrl = xmlUrl[countXmlUrl];
                    self.request_xml();
                }
                if (self.http_request.status == 200)
                {
                    self.xmlDoc = self.http_request.responseXML;
                    self.storage.setItem('domains_raw_xml', self.http_request.responseText);
                    self.main.peter_save_data();
                    self.timervar = setTimeout(function ()
                    {
// ########### Below line gives the error #############################
                        self.new_version_show_window();
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        },
        new_version_show_window: function ()
        {
...
}
```

the error that I am getting is:

> Error: self.new_version_show_window is
>   not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried moving the function definition for `new_version_show_window` above where it is called? Also, use a semicolon instead of a comma before `new_version_show_window`

Comment: How is the second part connected to the first part? Do you set the `prototype`?

Comment: @josh.trow: No, it seems to be an object literal. Properties are separated by comma.

Comment: @josh.trow - You are misunderstanding the code. There are no syntax errors that I can see.

Comment: You have to provide more information. We have to know where `new_version_show_window` is defined. Right now it could be everywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear from your code where `new_version_show_window` is defined. Maybe you could explicitly define it on self:

```
self.new_version_show_window = function () {
    /* ... */
}
```

instead. Or you could define it in the local namespace and use it directly in the setTimeout call:

```
self.timervar = setTimeout(function () {
    new_version_show_window();
 }, 2000);
```

or simply:

```
self.timervar = setTimeout(new_version_show_window, 2000);
```

Because of [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), the variables declared in the outer function is also available in the inner function.

## Edit

Thanks for posting the entire code. `new_version_show_window` is defined on `this.main`, so you must access it thusly:

```
self.timervar = setTimeout(function () {
    self.main.new_version_show_window();
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: If the (partial) object literal is used as prototype, then it should work. But we need more information...

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. However, since `self` closes over all the functions, it is basically a singleton - making little sense for a prototype.

Comment: The one one gives me this error:  
`Error: missing : after property id`

and the second one gives me this error:
`Error: new_version_show_window is not defined`

Comment: @Magnar: True... did not thought about that. Then it is even more mysterious to me ;). You are probably right, but actually we cannot say anything for sure...

Comment: @Ryan: As I said, we actually need the complete code. There is no way to tell what you did wrong because we don't know in which scope the second part is.

Comment: Yes, the first would have to be placed after the object literal. And for the second to work, you need to define the function in the local namespace - also moving it out of the object literal.

Comment: Just thought it would be simpler to write the important parts instead of the entire big file... but the code is open source so no worries :)

Comment: `new_version_show_window` is defined on this.main, so you have to call `self.main.new_version_show_window();`

Comment: @Ryan:  @Magnar is right. There might still be other problems with your code though. If you have time, think about a different structure ;)

Comment: That worked! Thanks guys! Don't know when JS got this complicated... I used to work with some simple stuff a couple of years back and am just getting back into it. Anonymous functions... encapsulated objects... never did/had that before and am quite lost. Would be in deep poop if it was not for SO and you wonderful people... thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, Ryan. And welcome back to JavaScript! A little rant: While JavaScript has some concepts that were in little use some years ago, and can be hard to grasp (like closures and prototypal inheritance) - it doesn't have to be as complicated as seen in that file you're maintaining. Using better patterns lets you write crisp and clear code in JavaScript just as nicely as in other languages. :-)

Comment: Rant away! Am learning new stuff :) Mind giving me some examples of "better patterns"? Because to be honest I wrote some of what you saw in that file as "old school", then someone else came in and "encapsulated" the whole thing as my global variables were supposedly "exposed" and so was rejected by the mozilla editors. There were three others who also wrote it old school in that file so its a bit mishmashed.

Comment: There's a lot to catch up on, for sure. If you are serious about JavaScript, I can highly recommend spending a few hours watch Douglas Crockford lecture the Yahoo devs. His videos are available online, just google 'yui theater crockford'. They are entertaining (to me at least) and full of lessons. I can also highly recommend the book 'Test-Driven JavaScript Development', even if you're not that into TDD. It's an excellent primer, up to date and practical.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advise, shall follow all of it. Have a fab day!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `self` is a reserved word in JavaScript [1]. This could be causing you some problems so try naming the variable something different to start with.

[1] http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: @Jivings: Well, I can tell you that there is no problem using it in a browser context. Otherwise a lot of my code would be broken... It is definitely possible to define it as *local variable in a function*. There are no other predefined variables with which it could clash.

Comment: @Felix - Haha okay, tbh I think I've used it before also. I just didn't see anything else immediately wrong with the code.

Comment: Felix is right. It may be on those lists, but `self` causes no problems as a local variable at least. I've used it plenty without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of scope. new_version_show_window is only in scope in the construct in which is it called ( apparently a jQuery AJAX function of some sort). It will only be available to `my_great_masterpiece` if you define it outside the limited scope in which it now exists.